# list.asmx is giving authorized error in sharepoint using js

Tags: javascript, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

When i logged in with Administrator, I am able to access my list data with list.asmx web service.
But when i logged in with other user who is not primary administrator of the site, i got 401 unauthorised error.
Please provide some solution with other user.

Thanks,
Hiral

Comment: are you trying to access custom list or some SharePoint internal lists

Comment: Have you tried this? http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The user that you tried to login is not authorized to view the list. To do this, you need to login back as an administrator and go the members list add the specific user. And that should do it. :)